# Delphi - Single Quote in string

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I am trying to populate a string variable to use in a TQuery.

How do I get a single quote in a string variable. In the following code the ShowMessage comand displays the CompName correct as 'TestComp" but the value in sql_str is ''TestComp''?

I have tried using QuotedStr.

```
  CompName := 'TestComp';
  ShowMessage('SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE     lower(datname) = ''' + CompName + '''');
  sql_str := 'SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE lower(datname) = ''' + CompName + '''';
```

Comment: one word: Use parameters. Don't concatenate SQL queries, you are vulnerable to SQL Injection!!!

Comment: The `ShowMessage` and `sql_str` should result in the same string (apart from spacing which you've done differently in each case). Put a little effort into understanding your own problem so you can ask a question that makes sense. And please post a MCVE.

Answer (score 11):

You say you tried using `QuotedStr()`, but the code you showed is not using it.  It should look like this:

```pascal
CompName := 'TestComp';
sql_str := 'SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE lower(datname) = ' + QuotedStr(CompName);
ShowMessage(sql_str);
```

That being said, you really should be using a [parameterized query](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Parameters_in_Queries) instead of building SQL statements manually.  For example:

```pascal
Query1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE lower(datname) = :Name';
Query1.ParamByName('Name').AsString := 'TestComp';
```

Using a parameterized query has some major benefits:

1. it is a safer and more efficient way of preventing SQL injection attacks, since the DB engine validates and formats dangerous values for you.  Do not do it manually!
2. parameterized queries allows the DB engine to format the SQL statement safely and consistently.  This is important for things like date/time values, which can be expressed in strings format using any number of DB-specific localized formats.  This also allows you to specify any parameter values in their native data formats (integers, blobs, etc) without having to convert them to strings manually.  Let the DB engine handle all of the formatting for you.
3. an SQL statement that needs to be executed multiple times, but does not need to be changed between executions, can be optimized by pre-preparing it one time on the server-side and then executing it as-is on the client-side whenever needed.  This is faster and more efficient then creating a new SQL statement each time you want to perform a query.  This includes parameterized queries.  Since the syntax of a parameterized query does not change, you can pre-prepare it and then execute it multiple times with different parameter values as needed, eg:

   ```pascal
   Query1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE lower(datname) = :Name';
   Query1.Prepare;

   ...

   Query1.ParamByName('Name').AsString := 'some value';
   Query1.Open;
   // use result set as needed...
   Query1.Close;

   ...

   Query1.ParamByName('Name').AsString := 'some other value';
   Query1.Open;
   // use result set as needed...
   Query1.Close;

   ...

   Query1.UnPrepare;
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the point about caching of prepared sql by the data base engine. Often overlooked.

Comment: @remy Hope you can see the screen shots. You will see that even using QuotedStr I still get '' around TestComp

Comment: @Gerhard what screenshots?

Answer (score 3):

Your code already demonstrates the answer. Escape a single quote in a Delphi string by doubling the single quote. So this string has length 1 and that single character is a single quote:

```
 ''''
```

This is explained clearly by the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements#Character_Strings

> Two sequential apostrophes in a quoted string denote a single character, namely an apostrophe.

Beyond the question you asked I must commend SQL prepared queries and parameters to you. They will remove the need for quoting and avoid the terrible risk of SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works:

```
CompName := 'TestComp''; DROP TABLE pg_catalog.pg_students; --';

sql_str := 'SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE lower(datname) = ''' + CompName + '''';

ShowMessage(sql_str);
```

But might i also suggest you avoid SQL injection by using `QuotedStr`:

```
sql_str := 'SELECT datname '+#13#10+
           'FROM pg_catalog.pg_database'+#13#10+
           'WHERE lower(datname) = '+QuotedStr(CompName);
```

---

Example using SQL:

```
Connection.Execute(sql);
```

Hypothetical example using parameters. I don't know the syntax:

```
cmd: TADOCommand;

cmd := TADOCommand.Create;
cmd.Connection := Connection;
cmd.CommandText := 'SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database'+#13#10+
      'WHERE lower(datname) = %datname%';
cmd.AddParameter('datname', DataType_WVarChar);
cmd.ParamByName('datname').SetString(CompName);
cmd.Execute;
cmd.Free;
```

Comment: A better way to avoid SQL injection is to use parameterized queries instead of manually creating SQL query strings.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The one downside of parameterized queries is that you cannot see the final SQL that will be issued by the component.

Comment: The approach here does not avoid injection

Comment: @david This is the first time that I get to do with SQLaAlthough my system has been running for over 30 years (yes I am very old). Can you please explain to me what you mean by "Use parameters. Don't concatenate SQL queries"

Comment: @IanBoyd: many DBs have monitoring tools available for viewing SQL statements that get executed.

Comment: I have always been using '''' but now it is not working when I setup the variable CompName. I keep on getting '' around the value of CompName in sql_str. Is there anyway that I can send a screen shot of the debug screen

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sometimes you want it in the client; for example [caching a dataset in memory where the SQL is the cache key](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/3/stack-overflow-architecture-update-now-at-95-million-page-vi.html). Sometimes you don't have access to login to the server (e.g. in reality).

Comment: @IanBoyd the `TQuery.Text` property gives you the actual SQL that the DB executes. For a parameterized query, the parameter values are not part of the query string itself, so `Text` will not include them, only placeholders for them. If you need to use the actual parameter values as part of the cache key, then a parameterized query by itself will not work for the key. But you could associate a custom value with a parameterized query, and then combine the parameter values to that custom value, to create the key. Or, you could get the query text and append the parameter vales to the end of it

Comment: @IanBoyd You don't always need to login to a server to monitor outgoing SQL statements from the client side, you just need a client-side monitor.